Shaded area in circles via TikZ
I'm trying to create a coin like \texttwemoji{coin}. At this moment, the code below is the best I could do. Now, there are decorations in the lower part of the emoji (in brown and silver) which give 3D perspective which I don't now how it can be done in TikZ. Any help is very welcome. With thanks.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{twemojis}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{myflavescent}{rgb}{0.97, 0.91, 0.56}
\definecolor{mynaplesyellow}{rgb}{0.98, 0.85, 0.37}

\newcommand*\coin[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[orange!11!mynaplesyellow,scale=0.53,shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=5mm,fill=orange!55!myflavescent,line width=0.3mm] (char) {#1};}}
            

\begin{document}

\coin{{\color{myflavescent}\textbf{\EUR}}}

{\large\texttwemoji{coin}}

\end{document}



See section 70.3 (page 781) of the TikZ manual.

Something like this (needs fine-tuning):

\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{twemojis}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{myflavescent}{rgb}{0.97, 0.91, 0.56}
\definecolor{mynaplesyellow}{rgb}{0.98, 0.85, 0.37}

\newcommand*\coin[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)i,
    my char/.style={scale=0.53,shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=5mm,line width=0.3mm},
  ]{%
    \node[orange!81!mynaplesyellow,fill=orange!95!myflavescent,my char,yshift=-0.4mm] (char1) {\phantom{#1}};
    \node[orange!11!mynaplesyellow,fill=orange!55!myflavescent,my char] (char) {#1};
    \clip (current bounding box.west |- char.center) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
    \fill[myflavescent!50!white,even odd rule] (char.center) circle [radius=1.2mm] (char.center) ++(0pt,-0.15pt) circle [radius=1.25mm];
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\coin{{\color{myflavescent}\textbf{\EUR}}}

{\large\texttwemoji{coin}}

\end{document}


Yes, it's very nice. I ran your code replacing the corresponding lines by \node[orange!81!mynaplesyellow,fill=orange!95!myflavescent,my char,yshift=-0.3mm] (char1) {\phantom{#1}}; and
\fill[myflavescent!50!white,even odd rule] (char.center) circle [radius=1.2mm] (char.center) ++(0pt,-0.2pt) circle [radius=1.2mm];
and the result is very close of \texttwemoji{coin}. Once more, thanks for help.

@CarlosMoura yes, I really needed to stop and I figured from your code you'd have no problem tweaking it ;).
